# Unify unmanaged assemblies into one

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I have many unmanaged assemblies in a project. They are C libraries.

I would like to have all of them as just one, containing all the dlls I need.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to combine all _.dll_ files and using them as a one file?

Comment: pkzip or something like that.

Comment: @SonerGönül , basically yes. I want to have them as resource and access them from the code.